# MYSQL REPLACE column values using prepared statements, string version

Tags: php, mysql, replace

I've got a scenario whereby I'm looking at updating the values in a category column with new values, based on the old values in the existing column. The categories are altered in a separate table, and need to be updated in this table to reflect the changes.

I'm using prepared statements and two arrays to vet the different values to be replaced:

```
$category = array($_POST['cat1'],$_POST['cat2'],$_POST['cat3'],$_POST['cat4']);
$oldCategory = array($_POST['catOld1'],$_POST['catOld2'],$_POST['catOld3'],$_POST['catOld4']);

for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
    $strg="UPDATE table_name SET CATEGORY = REPLACE (CATEGORY, ?, ?)";
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare($strg) or die($db->error());
    $sql->bind_param('ss', $oldCategory[$i], $category[$i]);
    $sql->execute();
}
```

I think it's the syntax of my REPLACE statement with regard to the prepared statement that results in just a hang, but can't find a reference anywhere online to the proper formatting. Any assistance appreciated. Thanks.

**Update:** Ok, one of those weird things: it's working now. Why? I'm not sure. Murphy's Law always hits us namesakes hard. Wrikken, you were right: there's nothing wrong with the syntax. Wish I could mod you up.

Hopefully, though, the above will be of use to someone else. It took me quite a bit and no on-line references to solve this problem. Hopefully useful.

Comment: It should work (`UPDATE... fieldname=REPLACE(fieldname, oldstring,newstring)`), but depending on your table, it could take quite a while ....

Comment: Table is tiny: max, 100 records. Not worried about the time. But no, I just get a hang, with not even any error messages returned, just a 500 error. Dang.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$strg="UPDATE table_name SET CATEGORY = REPLACE (CATEGORY,$oldCategory[$i],$category[$i])";
```

in the place of this :

```
$strg="UPDATE table_name SET CATEGORY = REPLACE (CATEGORY, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: I had tried that, and other variations, while trying to solve, even using mysqli_real_escape_string to ensure proper security: still no joy. Does this not eliminate the VALUES targets that the prepared statement needs? Anyway, still ends in a hang with no error messages forthcoming. Thanks, though.